# IPC Connection in child-process library is not duplex

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

The following javascript represents the parent process:

```
this.sso = fork('./app/utils/SSOproxy.js', [], {
    stdio: [0, 1, 2, 'ipc']
});    

//__handshake
this.sso.send({
    opcode:'ACK',
    params: [],
    ref: null
});
console.log('STEP_1');
//__main
process.on('message', ((msg)=>{
    switch (msg.opcode){
        case 'ACK':
            (msg.params[0] === 'ok')
                console.log('STEP_3');
            break;
```

It shows a partial implementation of a simple handshake protocol.
And the child process' partial:

```
process.on('message', ((msg)=>{
switch (msg.opcode){
    //handshake
    case 'ACK':
        process.send({
            opcode:'ACK',
            params:['ok'],
            ref: null
        });
        console.log('STEP_2');
        break;
```

My problem is that in the console (keep in mind both processes share all in/out/err streams) I do not observe `STEP_3`; and this is due to the absence of child to parent communication.
Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need listen child process (`this.sso` ) instead main process:

```
//__main
this.sso.on('message', ((msg)=>{
    switch (msg.opcode){
        case 'ACK':
            (msg.params[0] === 'ok')
                console.log('STEP_3');
            break;
```

Comment: Why? Surely the new process is still a polymorphism of event-emitter?

Comment: `Instances of the ChildProcess class are EventEmitters that represent spawned child processes.`: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess